# second ms sql server as backup

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, backup

As a small medical ngo we would like to have a copy of our sql server (ms sql 2010 express) on a laptop.

So if the power goes down we can at least read (no updating) the data.

Because it's unpredictable when the power goes down and we need the latest available data, the backup sql-db should continually be updated (like once every x minutes, or on every change, not once a day).

How can we do this? thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without moving to a new SQL Server version (Express supports none of the technology you need here); you could schedule regular/frequent backups with Windows Task Scheduler to push backups onto a shared drive on the laptop.  Then either manually restore (on power loss), or schedule regular restore jobs on the laptop using Windows Task Scheduler.  See MS link below.

Hacky, yep, but it should work - assuming you're not backing up a massive dB.

You'd be better off investing in a solid UPS which can keep your primary dB operational, or at least, to get it to shut down cleanly.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019698

Comment: we finally went for this option! thanks for all feedback! It gets the job done!

Answer (score 0):

log shipping, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx, and it's available in express, http://sqlmag.com/database-backup-and-recovery/poor-mans-disaster-recovery-use-log-shipping-sql-server-your-own-risk .

Comment: Express wont support HA,it is used as witness only:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Express Wont support Any HA feature,you can do it though,but i requires a lot of effort and i dont beleive you can keep your laptop online 24/7.So best would be go for SQL Azure

[image]